# A way to iterate creation of new SQL tables using a column from another SQL table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

My program aims to take values from an existing table and create a new table named from those values. I was able to check if it iterates with `print()`  but once I input `cur.execute()`, the program only makes the first table and then stops. What am I missing?

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('PSEIraw.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''SELECT STOCK_CODE FROM psei_raw''')
row = cur.fetchone()
for row in cur:
    stockcode='''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "''' + row[0] + '''" (Date DATE, Open DECIMAL, High DECIMAL, Low DECIMAL, Close Decimal, Volume DECIMAL)'''
    cur.execute(stockcode)

conn.commit()
```

**EDIT 1**
I plan on getting at most 50 rows per stock for stdev computations and volume comparisons. I know that designwise, this isn't the best but that's the process i am in now. Gist is to download EOD for all stocks in our exchange (200+ stocks) and have OHLC and volume that inserted per stock table.

**EDIT 2**

Done. just iterated and stored in a list then iterated again to make tables.

Comment: Creating a separate table for each stock code is almost certainly not the design decision you want to be making here.

Comment: even if you want to do something like this which totally not recommend, don't you need a loop for this kind of work?

Comment: I plan on getting at most 50 rows per stock for stdev computations and volume comparisons. I know that designwise, this isn't the best but that's the process i am in now. Gist is to download EOD for all stocks in our exchange (200+ stocks) and have OHLC and volume that inserted per stock table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cur.fetchall()` rather as in the below code

```
cur.execute('''SELECT stock_code FROM psei_raw''')
row = cur.fetchall()
for r in row:
    stockcode='''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "''' + str(r[0]) + '''"
                (
                 Date  DATE, 
                 Open  DECIMAL, 
                 High  DECIMAL, 
                 Low   DECIMAL, 
                 Close DECIMAL, 
                 Volume DECIMAL
                )
              '''
    cur.execute(stockcode)
```

where using `conn.commit()` is redundant because it's not a DML but a DDL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

```
row = cur.fetchone()  # <-- This skips your first row in the loop below
for row in cur:       # <-- and then you iterate over the remaining rows
    ...
```

The 2nd problem when you fix that one:

You're re-using the same cursor object `cur` before you've got all your rows fetched. `cur.execute(stockcode)` will make the first `cur` object useless. (Or will get weird iteration since it's been mutated/changed mid-loop.)

Either:

1. Fetch all rows first and then create all tables, or
2. Use a 2nd cursor object to create the tables:

   ```
   conn = sqlite3.connect('PSEIraw.sqlite')
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute('''SELECT STOCK_CODE FROM psei_raw''')
   # removed the line which was here cur.fetchone()

   table_cur = conn.cursor()  # another cursor object
   for row in cur:
       stockcode = '''CREATE TABLE...'''  # as before
       table_cur.execute(stockcode)

   conn.commit()
   ```